# Alternative to Initializer List of References

Tags: c++

I really needed and Initializer List of References but it seems that is not possible. The problem of being a copy is that I wanted to disable copy construction and because these copies call the destrutor afterwards what releases the resources(and should not happend).

My current (bad) alternative is using a bool to track if it was copy constructed so the resources are not released.

Another alternative is an Initializer List of Pointers but that makes it more verbose and would accept nullptr as well as being conceptually incorrect in my opinion.

I would really like an alternative using references or something along those lines (maybe move? I can't seem to make that work)

Comment: Any code example to demonstrate what you want to do? I was thinking maybe `std::ref` and `std::reference_wrapper`but probably not quite the right fit.

Comment: That really does it! I added an example working with std::reference_wrapper and a following question

Comment: If you have a follow on question, then make a new post.  There are several reasons and benefit to doing this. Firstly, you will increase your own rep potential, with a few more generally useful questions as opposed to one very specific one. You also render the existing answer incomplete and compel the author to make an amendment and drag the author into a question and answer session that they may not have the wish to engage in.

Comment: That does seem a better option. Thank you

Comment: Suggest reverting the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want an initializer list of references of references to put in a container. So, you are looking for a reference type, right? If it's so, check the **Reference Wrappers**. It allows references to be the type of containers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct A {
    A() { std::cout << "A()" << std::endl; }
    A(const A&) = delete;
    ~A() { std::cout << "~A()" << std::endl; }
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    A a1;
    A a2;
    A a3;

    {
        // OK: don't call copy constructor during creation
        std::initializer_list<std::reference_wrapper<A>> ilist{ a1, a2, a3 };
        // OK: don't call destructor when "ilist" leaves the scope
    }

    {
        // ERROR: can't create the list because copy constructor is deleted
        std::initializer_list<A> va{ a1, a2, a3 };
    }


    // Destructors called here

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That seems to do it. That said if I call "inline" it doesn't work, is it because it's using rvalue or something along those lines? I'm Gonna edit a simple example to explain

Comment: Gonna remove my edit due to suggestion of creating new question